# Trouble saving wp_dropdown_pages()

Tags: theme-options

I'm really hoping that someone can help me out here, I'm trying to give the admin the ability to choose a page for a button to link to. I've created the select using...

```
wp_dropdown_pages($args)
```

... and am creating the arguments via...

```
$args = array(
  'echo'  => 1,
  'selected' => $the_link,
  'name'  => 'theme_option[the_link]');
```

... and have attempted to save the value generated

```
$input['the_link'] = (int) $input['the_link'];
```

... but so far no luck. The selected option just resets once the form has been sent, and it doesn't look like the value is getting saved at all. Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: Post the code surrounding this line: `$input['the_link'] = (int) $input['the_link'];`

Comment: First of all, check the received data when the form is submitted : `var_dump($_REQUEST); die();`. Is the displayed value the intended one ?

Comment: @ColoursB Please provide whole code so that we can debug it.

Comment: The whole shebang is here at http://pastebin.com/7TvvS2gP

Answer (score 0):

Edit your args as following:

```
$args = array(
    'echo'      => 1,
    'selected'  => $options['the_link'],
    'name'      => 'critter_theme_options[the_link]'
);
```

No setting with the name 'theme_option' is set.